# Error: no such column: rango_category.views

Tags: python, django

I am working through the Tango with Django tutorial, in the [exercises for the fifth section](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models.html#exercises), I stumbled.  I used solutions for another StackOverflow question on this topic, but I kept getting this error:

> Error: no such column: rango_category.views

Here is my code:

populate_rango.py

```
    import os

    def populate():
         python_cat = add_cat('Python', views=128, likes=64)

         add_page(cat=python_cat,
         title="Official Python Tutorial",
         url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")
    add_page(cat=python_cat,
         title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
         url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
         title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
         url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat("Django", views=64, likes=32)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
         title="Official Django Tutorial",
         url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
         title="Django Rocks",
         url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
         title="How to Tango with Django",
         url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks", views=32, likes=16)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
         title="Bottle",
         url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
         title="Flask",
         url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    # Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
            for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
                    print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

    def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
        p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, views=views)[0]

    def add_cat(name, views=0, likes=0):
        c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name, views=views, likes=likes)[0]
        return c

    # Start execution here!

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "Starting Rango population script..."
      os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','tango_with_django_project.settings')
        from rango.models import Category, Page
        populate()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from rango.models import Category, Page

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'category', 'url')

class CatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('views', 'likes')

admin.site.register(Category, CatAdmin)
admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

Hope you guys can help out!

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py syncdb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you're getting this error because the table or column wasn't actually created in your database.  If you already ran `django-admin.py syncdb`, you might want to look at the actual structure created.

Here's some documentation you may want to look into as well.
[syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)
[south](http://south.aeracode.org/)

Comment: How do I take a look at the structure created?  I also deleted the data from the structure and then ran the model again, and it still gave me the error

Comment: @user3103499 You need to generate sql output. Look for builtin manage.py commands in the django docs. Also did you follow my advice. Try to delete the whole database and then run syncdb.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities that to get this error
1) You added extra field to model after doing the syncdb.
2) you added new class to model.py file in django.

Solution for this is:

First install south by using command

```
    for windows: **easy_install south**     //for that you need to go to the script folder of python folder in c drive.

    for linux: **sudo easy_install south**
```

Then follow the steps which are included here [migration tutorials](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#the-first-migration)

step1- python manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --initial

step-2 python manage.py migrate your_app_name

if you made any changes in model then

```
 1) python manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --auto
 2) python manage.py migrate your_app_name
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `views` attribute, you cannot just run `syncdb`. Syncing database works only when you add/remove the whole model, not when you change it.

You have two options.

1. Use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
2. Remove the database file and then `syncdb` again after adding new model fields.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, after I changed to **str** instead of unicode, it works. (Maybe you are like me, using Python 3)